# How to migrate .Net Framework service reference to .Net Standard service reference

Tags: wcf, .net-standard-2.0

We're migrating our old .Net Framework code to .Net Standard.  One of the projects had a wcf service reference that I was able to recreate in the new .Net Standard project.  However, the generated code is different in that the old one had the following with an empty constructor for the object, while the .Net Standard one does not.  Is there a common workflow for converting this so I can have an empty constructor in the new version?

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class TasksClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WebServiceProxy.Tasks.ITasks>, WebServiceProxy.Tasks.ITasks {
            
            public TasksClient() {
            }
            
            public TasksClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                    base(endpointConfigurationName) {
            }
            
            public TasksClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                    base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
            }....
```

The new one looks like this.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    public partial class TasksClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Tasks.ITasks>, Tasks.ITasks
    {
        
        public TasksClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }
```

Comment: The .NET standard is different from .NET framework in that constructors are not automatically generated. The configuration of the two is different. You can look at the description of [this case](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3914).